# schedule meeting in Teams from sharepoint portal

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, microsoft-teams

I have SharePoint 2016, and I have a task to schedule meeting in Microsoft Teams from Sharepoint portal programmatically Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no out of the box capability to do this with SharePoint Server. You would need to create something like a [Remote] Event Receiver that called the Graph API to [CreateEvent](https://docs.microsoft.com/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with an online meeting.

Since your question is general and open ended, investigate this method and come back with *specific* questions you might have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, What kind of Graph API I can use to work with teams?
Do you have a link for documentation?

Comment: The linked CreateEvent API is what you'll want to use (Exchange Online is used for scheduling meetings). There is also a Teams API which you can find in the ToC on the same page.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I will check it now.